# how to combine values of two different arrays in php

Tags: php, mysql

I am having two arrays in php and I want to combine the values of these two arrays

this is my first array

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      'Restaurant' => string 'Taj' (length=3)
      'TableNo' => string '1' (length=1)
      'Status' => string 'Occupied' (length=8)
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      'Restaurant' => string 'Taj' (length=3)
      'TableNo' => string '2' (length=1)
      'Status' => string 'Vacant' (length=6)
```

This is my second array

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      'MenuGrp' => string 'Deserts' (length=7)
  1 => 
    array (size=1)
      'MenuGrp' => string 'Snacks' (length=6)
```

and I want to combine these arrays to final array as

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      'Restaurant' => string 'Taj' (length=3)
      'TableNo' => string '1' (length=1)
      'Status' => string 'Occupied' (length=8)
      'MenuGrp' => string 'Snacks' (length=6)
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      'Restaurant' => string 'Taj' (length=3)
      'TableNo' => string '2' (length=1)
      'Status' => string 'Vacant' (length=6)
      'MenuGrp' => string 'Deserts' (length=7)
```

how to get this array please help me.

Comment: Also take a look at array_combine()

Comment: array_merge adds to rows to the main array. i want the rows to be added to the sub array

Answer (score 0):

```
$resultsarray = array_merge($array1,$array2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try
array_merge or array_combine functions.

```
<?php
$a = array('green', 'red', 'yellow');
$b = array('avocado', 'apple', 'banana');
$c = array_combine($a, $b);

print_r($c);
?> 


<?php
$array1 = array("color" => "red", 2, 4);
$array2 = array("a", "b", "color" => "green", "shape" => "trapezoid", 4);
$result = array_merge($array1, $array2);
print_r($result);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

`array_merge_recursive()` will not work in this instance as your keys are integer. It would only work if they were strings. The simplest way to achieve it would be to loop over one of your arrays, check if the key exists in the second array, and if it does, combine the two:

```
$output = array();
foreach ($array1 as $key => $arr) {
  if (!empty($array2[$key])) {
    $output[$key] = array_merge($arr, $array2[$key]);
  }
}
```

Which would output (`var_dump($output)`):

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      'Restaurant' => string 'Taj' (length=3)
      'TableNo' => int 1
      'Status' => string 'Occupied' (length=8)
      'MenuGrp' => string 'Deserts' (length=7)
  1 => 
    array
      'Restaurant' => string 'Taj' (length=3)
      'TableNo' => int 2
      'Status' => string 'Vacant' (length=6)
      'MenuGrp' => string 'Snacks' (length=6)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$array_combined = array_merge_recursive($array_one, $array_two);
```

**Refer Here [array merge recursive](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php)**